# Is it okay to use Polymorphic Association to show different types of users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I'd just like to ask if what I'm doing makes sense for the app that I'm making (junior dev level).

Basically the app involves doctors, clients, and admins (for now). Each has their own profile page and can supposedly do different things. I also have a User class for the sign up process.

My rationale behind choosing PA is that everyone logs in as a User, and I would like to separate the "being a doctor" stuff from the "being a user" stuff. Is this a good idea?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  belongs_to :profile, polymorphic: true

end

class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, as: :profile, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user

  ## doctor stuff

  delegate :email, :password, to: :user
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, as: :profile, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user

  ## client stuff

  delegate :email, :password, to: :user
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it looks very reasonable to separate the person type information (Doctor, Client, etc.) from the User type information. You may want to consider naming the association person rather than profile, but that's not terribly significant. Yes, I think the polymorphic association will probably accomplish what you want to.

Comment: Thanks @Coenwulf. I'm about 80% convinced that this is the way to go, but upon reading [Enterprise Rails](http://enterpriserails.chak.org/full-text/chapter-10-multiple-table-inheritance) I am worried about the database integrity. For example, I can create a Doctor without an email address, which is horrible for me. Is this solvable?

Comment: It looks like you are storing email on the User. Is this a problem because User _must_ have an email address but Doctor does not need one? If so is this because Doctors aren't necessarily Users? Can you give more detail about the situation or what validations you will have?

Comment: Oh man I didn't have validations yet, I just got the thing working. Guess I should put validations then check the problem again. Yup, all Doctors are Users and should require an email address.

Comment: Then just use validation that validates presence of email address. That isn't really directly affected by the decision about polymorphic associations. Here's the guide to get started with validation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html

Comment: Everything's working now. I just added validations and after discovering Active Record error messages I got all tests to passed. I appreciate the help, @Coenwulf. Now to just hope this schema is the right one...